# Groupby per user id in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like help performing a `groupby` per user in Python pandas. Here is some sample code to illustrate the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user1', 'user1',
                              'user2', 'user2'],
                   'condition': ['pl', 'md', 'pl', 'md'],
                   'value': [2, 4, 40, 42]})

df.groupby(['condition']).mean()
```

In this example, the average difference between users between the "pl" and "md" conditions is the same, but the aggregate difference is not.

How do I perform aggregate functions (mean, max, median) per user? I've looked at a few answers to this question but couldn't find an answer. I'd like to note that it may be possible to answer this specific question using the `diff` function, but I'd like to run different types of aggregate functions, so learning how to `groupby` per user more generally is my goal.

EDIT: one of the commenters suggested this solution

```
df.groupby(['user'])['value'].agg(['mean','max','median'])
```

And, I should have clarified: I'm looking for the aggregate difference given the difference between each user. This function creates a table of the mean and max for each other.

Rather, the mean function, for instance, should return a difference of 2.

Thanks for any help and let me know if I can make this question earlier to answer.

Comment: `df.groupby(['user'])['value'].agg(['mean','max','median'])`?

Comment: unfortunately, that gives the mean by for each user, rather than control for the difference between each user. I'll update the question

Comment: does each user have two rows, each for one condition `pl` and `md`?